# Query is running forever in Azure Sql (Update query)

Tags: sql, azure

Today I noticed a slowness in SQL Azure, besides I was able to analyze that there is a query running for a long time.

Is there any way to kill this query? I can't find it anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the long running queries and session id corresponding to them through below query. We can customize it still:

```
 select
     r.session_id,
     s.login_name,
     c.client_net_address,
     s.host_name,
     s.program_name,
     st.text, s.status
 from sys.dm_exec_requests r
 inner join sys.dm_exec_sessions s
 on r.session_id = s.session_id
 left join sys.dm_exec_connections c
 on r.session_id = c.session_id
 outer apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) st
 where client_net_address is not null and text is not null and s.status = 'running'
```

Then we can run the KILL command with session id from above query:

```
KILL <Session_id>
```

Referenced Article: [Long Running Queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46009/get-username-and-or-ip-address-responsible-for-a-query)

Please note above queries do not take into account the query id. So if we want to do it for that specific query id, we need to find the specific session id for that query text and then terminate it.